# Facebook - Unable to create an app

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I am new to developer.facebook.com and want to create app. When I go to this URL `https://developers.facebook.com/apps` It is not showing any button having `+ create new app`

I have created an app previously and deleted it later as it was of no use to me. Now can anyone tell me what should I do to create a new app?

Comment: I feel like I just saw this question 2 hours ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm having the same issue right now. I had some apps and I removed them. Now I cannot create any app.

Edit:

Found the solution in another post from 4 hours ago.

http://developers.facebook.com/setup

Comment: *What* worked? ;-) It would help others to include a summary of the "fix", not just a link. So this answer is still useful if that link ever breaks.